# sharepoint 2013 dashboard designer not connected to SSAS datasources

Tags: 2013, dashboard-designer-2013, sql-analysis-services, bi

I created a new fresh SharePoint 2013 farm with two servers ( win 2012 R2)

1. Application server ( running, secure store,performance point
   service, )
2. wfe server

after that i created a simple BI site  and opened dashboard designer and try to connect to SSAS server.

> SSAS SERVER   ( SQL SERVER 2008 R2 ( 10.50.2868.0)

**Problem:**

When  i connect to ssas server database from dashboard designer , it can not load any databases and database list is always empty.

when i enable  verbose logs, i found below errors in application server logs.

> An unexpected error occurred.  Error 33056.   Exception details:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException:  Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient,  Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.   File name:
>   'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'      at
>   Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BIMonitoringServiceApplication.GetRenderCo

**Note:**

this SSAS datasource is in production server,  it already sharepoint 2010 Bi site connected   to these data sources and every thing working perfectly.

but from sharpoint 2013 there is no connectivity to this same ssas server

when i search in the net i found some people say to install

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978
(Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Feature Pack)

but it can solve my issue and not disturb sharepoint 2010 production.

Answer (score 0):

if you want full access to the built-in reports in the PowerPivot management dashboard. Some reports in the dashboard use ADOMD.NET to access internal data that provides reporting data on PowerPivot query processing and server health in the farm.

This thing required the IIS reset,So a down time for the farm.

But i highly advise you to perform these steps in lower /test farm 1st then test, test and test. Once satisfied then you should install it in production.

check this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2011/12/21/will-sql-server-quot-denali-quot-models-work-as-performancepoint-data-sources.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on SQL server version installed 
if you have SQL server 2014 on the back-end you might need to install [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 ADOMD.NET](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=42295)

Then update web.config file of PerformancePoint webservices to redirectbinding from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\WebServices\PpsMonitoringServer\web.config`

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="9.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
```

To

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" /
```